# Optimize search result with JavaScript/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am looking for, if i can optimize search on my web page.

what i am doing right now is ,

I provided search box, where user can search account number on keyup.

I have 80K-90K data in MySql database table for search
(tables are indexed and using primary keys).

On page load, i use to load all that data related to account from database to page as in HTML format, than user can search account on page in HTML.

By the above approach page load gets slow,

So i have tried one more option as to search database table directly through Ajax call on keyup rather than loading all data on page load.

But still searching thousand Or Millions of data on each keyup, is not efficient solution for searching and it took lot of time.

I am curious how can i improve and fast search results?

If there is, any client site possible solution for search optimization?

Comment: Optimizations are done in two ways. #1 - do less work. #2 - distribute work on more machines. In your case, without any data available, it's impossible to tell you what to do. People usually use `LIKE` for searching and autocompleting using default MySQL configuration on top of it which, naturally, will be snail slow.

Comment: @N.B. Hang on - what about doing the same amount of work more efficiently?

Comment: @Strawberry - do less work implies that, doesn't it? :)

Comment: Hard to help without knowing what is actually working slowly in your system.  Is it the query itself? Is the the transmittal of data related to the query?

Comment: @N.B. and Mike : I cant share data as its customers private data with live site.Here what i am looking for a solution on code level on client site with Javascript/Ajax, ignores machine dependance as of now(query response, MySql server).

Comment: I am thinking of getting data on local-storage of browser(FF, Chrome) and than query local storage rather calling back to database.but this solution will not work in IE8 or below

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can do to make the process more efficient.

1. Use jQuery's [autocomplete library](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).
2. Create index on your database table which has this particular data. This will help especially if you have millions of records.
3. Set a minimum character limit for user to enter, like say 3, so it automatically narrows the data to search.

Comment: In addition to #3 you can also add a timeout function that will only start searching after X ms without a key press.

Comment: Thanks avnishkgaur, but i had already applied all of the suggest solutions.